# Why do I need to break out of the loop here? minSubArrayLen

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

I wrote a function that returns the minLength of the subarray in arr with consecutive elements where the sum is larger than the num.
in my own solution I didn't break out of the loop which I needed; however, I still don't understand why I need to break out of this loop.

```
//returns the minlen of the contiguous subarray which sum is greater than or equal to the num

function minSubArrayLen(arr, num){
  //define variables
  let total = 0;
  let start = 0;
  let end = 0;
  let minLen = Infinity;

  while (start < arr.length){

    //when total is less then the num increase end and add it to the total
    if (total < num && end < arr.length){
      total += arr[end];
      end++;

    //when total is larger than the num start looping from the next start and subtract the previous start from the total
    } else if (total >= num){
      minLen = Math.min(minLen, (end - start));
      total -= arr[start];
      start++;

      //need to break because
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return minLen === Infinity ? 0: minLen;
}



//test
console.log(minSubArrayLen([1,2,3,4,5], 200));
console.log(minSubArrayLen([5,2,3,1,6], 7));
console.log(minSubArrayLen([1,2,20,4,10], 20));
```

Comment: Can you explain what you expect with your examples?

Answer (score 0):

For the first set of inputs, your `total` (second argument to the function) is bigger than the actual total of array elements. Your first two conditions are not sufficient to handle this set of input.

Based on the inputs, your loop only goes inside the first condition, and only the `end` variable changes; `start` doesn't change because `total` is never greater than or equal to `num`.

Your while loop depends on `start` which is never modified inside the if block, so the condition for repeating the while loop always evaluates to true. Once the `if` condition is not true for the first set of arguments, the `else if` condition is also not true, so without `else { break; }` it goes in an infinite loop.

You could resolve this by refining your test for entering the while loop so that it depends on a variable that is modified within the loop.